# Rotativa pdf failing in shared server with restriction for exe files

Tags: asp.net-core, wkhtmltopdf, rotativa

Using Rotativa (from npm) for generating reports as pdf in my .Net Core3.1 Web Application and has been working fine until recently when there was a change in our Host Server.

Our previous server (shared), where it was working, allowed exe files and had the foll. files in place (\wwwroot\Rotativa)

- wkhtmltopdf.exe
- wkhtmltoimage.exe
- help-wkhtmltoimage.txt
- help-wkhtmltopdf.txt

However the new server (shared) to which we migrated does not allow executable files for security reasons. For this reason, files wkhtmltopdf.exe & wkhtmltoimage.exe were denied access and cannot be present in Rotativa folder. Since then Rotativa pdf generation started failing.

I tried using some dll files like msvcp120.dll, msvcp140.dll, msvcr120.dll, vcruntime140.dll, wkhtmltox.dll etc. in the same location ; But no luck yet.

How to get over this and get Rotativa working again?

Comment: It won't work while have no permissions to wkhtmltodf.exe or the Rotativa folder.

Comment: ok..If so, do you have any recommendations for an alternative to Rotativa ?

Comment: Most of the HTMLtoPDFconvertor needs libraries or exe. You could try [DinkToPdf](https://github.com/rdvojmoc/DinkToPdf) or others which only requires xxx.dll file in the root of your project.